# How to let the user switch/change the theme of a browser ASP MVC Bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, themes

I'm building an ASP MVC web app with Bootstrap, that needs the theme to be switchable/user change capable for dynamic themes. Can someone show me how to ***let the user test/colors/change the theme of a website, on the front end.***

I notice a lot of sites, like WP theme's, let you try out the theme in different colors, icons etc.

- For e.g. on the left side, click on the gear : 
  http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/?theme=Nexus

I also see that you can apply different styles with stylebot

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en

Another requirement for x508 handicap is that, I need the users to pick their own color contrasts for text, is this possible?